# Empty response after configure the spring-boot project to use SSL

Tags: java, spring, ssl

I configure SSL in my current spring-boot project this way:

generation of the keystore file:

```
keytool -genkey -alias ... -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validi
ty 3650 -dname "CN=Kleber Mota, OU=lojadesoftware, O=Itabuna, L=Brazil, ST=Unknows, C=BR" -keypass ... -storepass ...
```

application.properties (added this lines):

```
# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=...
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store-password=...
server.ssl.key-password=...
```

after that, when I run the application and go to url localhost:8443 I only got an error "Empty response from server".

Anyone can give a hint of what I am missing here?

Comment: did you go to `https://localhost:8443` or `http://localhost:8443`? The former should work.

Answer (score 0):

if your application is running and has explicit mapping for (/) try the following, it should work

```
   curl k https://localhost:8443 

   curl -k  https://localhost:8443 ( this one is insecure)

   curl -k -1 https://localhost:8443
```